# Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFilesAsync hangs in FCU (1709)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am seeing some weird behaviour when using `GetFilesAsync` API.

```cs
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    ...
    await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFilesAsync();
    ...
}
```

This code works in creator update SDK but not FCU. My understanding is that I am not required to declare any capabilities as I am trying to get files from the installation directory

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem... I dont have any problems to perform the above code

Comment: strange. I am using windows template studio generated code. Installation issue? someone reported that they faced this issue if the installed version of SDK and the target OS varies. which is not the case with my installation.

Comment: I just created a new project and added your line into the code behind. There wasnt an exception and I checked the return of the method, which looked valid